# Laravel display a custom message in Maintenance Mode

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm checking out Laravel docs for Maintenance Mode:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/configuration#maintenance-mode

When you execute the command `php artisan down`, it will put the application under maintenance mode, and return the 503.blade.php view.

Works good, but there is an option I can't really make work.. when I do:

```
php artisan down --message='Upgrading Database' --retry=60
```

I want to display the message in the view, I tried accessing the obvious choice with `{{ $message }}` without success, returns undefined variable.

My question is: how to access it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By default [503.blade.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.3/resources/views/errors/503.blade.php) view doesn't use this message.

This message is available in a JSON formatted file named `storage/framework/down` [generated by `php artisan down`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/DownCommand.php) command.

You could do something like this to access the directly the message in your view:

```
{{ json_decode(file_get_contents(storage_path('framework/down')), true)['message'] }}
```

A cleaner way is to use the `$exception` variable and include in your view `{{ $exception->getMessage() }}` like suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41654147/107282).

Under the hood, the `CheckForMaintanceMode` middleware reads the [message and other data from the file](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php#L41) and thrown a `MaintanceModeException` with this data.

**Edit:** After Laravel 8, the payload that creates the `storage/framework/down` command has changed and doesn't [include the exception message](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/DownCommand.php#L69). You should use the `{{ $exception->getMessage() }}` instead on Laravel 8+.

Comment: @jezmck thanks for the link. I thought the original was a little dirty! {{ $exception->getMessage() }} is the way to get the message properly :)

Comment: Antony answer is really a cleaner way. I've referenced his answer with some extra information. Under the hood Laravel still reads from that file :)

Comment: This doesn't work anymore for latest laravel 8

Comment: What do you mean by "do something like this"? Where exactly do I have to write that code?

Comment: @peeter in your blade views file... ?

Answer (score 39):

Actually you don't need that "json_decode" stuff, as all the "error" views (including `503.blade.php`) have `$exception` variable.

So you may just use `{{ $exception->getMessage() }}` in your view and you will get the exact value that you have passed to `artisan down --message` command.

Comment: And also may use {{ $exception->retryAfter }} to show the time.

Answer (score 4):

If you want detailed information (not just message) on your maintenance page, you  can also use `$exception->retryAfter`(Int), `$e->willBeAvailableAt`(Carbon) and `$e->wentDownAt`(Carbon).
Of course you need to set **--retry** parameter in artisan command.